# Plotly Dashboard Offline

Tags: plotly

In the Plotly Dashboard tutorial, the fill a box with a plot using a 'fileId'.
How would you go about doing so if I had generated the plot offline?

```
import re

def fileId_from_url(url):
    """Return fileId from a url."""
    raw_fileId = re.findall("~[A-z]+/[0-9]+", url)[0][1: ]
    return raw_fileId.replace('/', ':')

def sharekey_from_url(url):
    """Return the sharekey from a url."""
    if 'share_key=' not in url:
        return "This url is not 'sercret'. It does not have a secret key."
    return url[url.find('share_key=') + len('share_key='):]

fileId_1 = fileId_from_url(url_1)
fileId_2 = fileId_from_url(url_2)

box_a = {
    'type': 'box',
    'boxType': 'plot',
    'fileId': fileId_1,
    'title': 'scatter-for-dashboard'
}
```